# Mastering : 41000Hz or 96000Hz?

Tags: sound-design, mastering

Which sample rate should be used when exporting mastered audio?

Example : I want to export my mastered electro track.

Comment: hi noob, this is a very minimal question. how did you record the audio and at which samplerate? what do you mean by 'mastered audio'?

Comment: Right now I usually record at 44100hz. I was wondering what would be better because a guy mentioned that his sound changed (and sounded better in his ears) when he recorded at 96khz.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the end purpose is a CD or MP3/FLAC deliverable, 44100hz - not 41000.  Nothing wrong with keeping a 96k master copy around if you feel its needed.

Answer (score 1):

I work to two golden rules in this regard:

1. Always keep the "native" format the same
2. Always avoid interpolation

Native format in this sense means that if your project from your sequencer settings is 44.1Khz then the "native" rate for your project is also 44.1Khz, if it's for video this should be 48Khz.

What do I mean by avoiding interpolation?

Performing non equal calculations introduces interpolation meaning that the numbers are not equally devised.  If I'm working on audio for a CD I'll often work at 88.2Khz so when the final master is made for 44.1Khz there is no interpolation going on since 88.2Khz is exactly twice 44.1Khz.

Poeple often ramp it right up to 96Khz for a CD job which is madness since you are going to have to interpolate at some point.

Pow-r is useful here but why introduce the problem in the first place?